# Firebase queryEqualToValue get Key in Swift 2.3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing a small application in iOS using Swift and Firebase. I am having trouble querying a data and retrieving the value. 
My firebase realtime database is this:

```
"qrcode" : {
   "postsedation_room" : "http://bing.com",
   "preprocedure_room" : "http://google.com",
   "presedation_room" : "http://en.m.wikipedia.org"
}
```

I would like to make this query :

```
let query = rootRef.child("qrcode").queryEqualToValue("http://bing.com")

query.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
   print(snapshot)
})
```

print a key value "postsedation_room". 
At this point the result of print is
`Snap (qrcode) <null>` could you help me so that I can print key given the child value?

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 how would I go about changing my code to fix this null problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So if you attach a value observer the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

So in your observer you'll need to handle that list. The easiest way to do that is to iterate over it:

```
let query = rootRef.child("qrcode").queryOrderedByValue().queryEqualToValue("http://bing.com")

query.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
   for child in snapshot.children {
      print(child.key)
   }
})
```

Alternatively you can observe a single `childAdded` eventL

```
let query = rootRef.child("qrcode").queryEqualToValue("http://bing.com")

query.observeSingleEventOfType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
   print(snapshot.key)
})
```

Comment: I tried both ways, in both cases it returned null... do you have any other suggestions?