# Firebase database query for specific selection

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make a selection on a Firebase database on xcode and present the results on a table, but the results that I get are very strange. It's like it runs the for loop on the same entry. Most probably because of the table.

```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemCell", for: indexPath)
let groceryItem = items[indexPath.row]

// Below is code to query users in Firebase to check if it is the current user.

let selection = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "addedByUser").queryEqual(toValue : user.email)

selection.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with:{ (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
  if let value = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
    print(value)
  }
})
//End of code


//if user.email == groceryItem.addedByUser {
cell.textLabel?.text = groceryItem.name

cell.detailTextLabel?.text = groceryItem.addedByUser
// }
toggleCellCheckbox(cell, isCompleted: groceryItem.completed)

return cell
}
```

and the Firebase is:

```
 {
  "expense-items" : {
    "20170509" : {
      "addedByUser" : "michael_papado@crymary.gr",
      "amount" : 37,
      "categoryType" : "Shopping",
      "completed" : false,
      "name" : "Dijon",
      "paymentType" : "Cash"
    },
    "zambon" : {
      "addedByUser" : "harry@crymary.gr",
      "amount" : 13,
      "categoryType" : "Shopping",
      "completed" : false,
      "name" : "zambon",
      "paymentType" : "CreditCard"
    },
    "zouzouni" : {
      "addedByUser" : "harry@crymary.gr",
      "amount" : 24,
      "categoryType" : "Kids",
      "completed" : false,
      "name" : "zouzouni",
      "paymentType" : "Cash"
    }
  }
}
```

Only the 20170509 is from the user that is logged in and I get 3 times the 20170509 entry.
How I can count the results of the selection in order to populate the table with the correct results?

Comment: Have you checked out this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40316200/firebase-queryequaltovalue-get-key-in-swift-2-3

Comment: Also try to add this at the end too: 
.queryLimited(toFirst: 1)

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: @arvidurs if I add the code you wrote, then in case I need to get the results from the other user won't this limit them to the first one only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was all thinking wrong. I should not check the list on the tableView function.
All I had to do is populate a new list at the viewDidLoad and use this all along.

```
    if FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser != nil {
  let selection = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "addedByUser").queryEqual(toValue : FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.email)

      selection.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with:{ (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in

        var newItems: [ListItem] = []

        for item in snapshot.children {
          let listItem = ListItem(snapshot: item as! FIRDataSnapshot)
          newItems.append(listItem)
        }

        self.items = newItems

        self.tableView.reloadData()
      })
}
```